# Neo4j GDS: Cannot use Cypher to make a complex projection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following query from the [GDS documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/projections/graph-project-cypher-projection/#graph-project-cypher-projection-filtered) shows how to create a GDS projection via Cypher:

```
MATCH (source) OPTIONAL MATCH (source)-[r:READ]->(target)
WHERE r.numberOfPages IS NOT NULL
WITH gds.graph.project('existingNumberOfPages', source, target, { relationshipProperties: r { .numberOfPages } }) AS g
RETURN
  g.graphName AS graph, g.nodeCount AS nodes, g.relationshipCount AS rels
```

This is my code and i want to create a customized projection:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) 
WHERE type(r) IN [
    'Environment_related_eQTL',
    'GO term\'s relationshipbiological_process',
    'GO term\'s relationshipcellular_component',
    'GO term\'s relationshipmolecular_function',
    'Gene and GO\'s biological_process term relationship',
    'Gene and GO\'s cellular_component term relationship',
    'Gene and GO\'s molecular_function term relationship',
    'Genes_regulated_by_methylation',
    'Phenotypes_affected_by_snp',
    'SNP_belongTo_Gene',
    'TF_regulates',
    'TranseQTL_belongTo_Gene',
    'TranseQTL_to_gene',
    'ciseQTL_belongTo_Gene',
    'ciseQTL_influence_Gene',
    'environmenteqtl_id_on',
    'gene_to_TFfamily',
    'subaloaction',
    'Gene_Phenotypes_affected_by_Gene_from_twas_araPhenotype'
]
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT id(n)) + COLLECT(DISTINCT id(m)) AS allNodeIDs
MATCH (source)-[r]->(target) WHERE  id(source) IN allNodeIDs AND id(target) IN allNodeIDs AND type(r) IN [
    'Environment_related_eQTL',
    'GO term\'s relationshipbiological_process',
    'GO term\'s relationshipcellular_component',
    'GO term\'s relationshipmolecular_function',
    'Gene and GO\'s biological_process term relationship',
    'Gene and GO\'s cellular_component term relationship',
    'Gene and GO\'s molecular_function term relationship',
    'Genes_regulated_by_methylation',
    'Phenotypes_affected_by_snp',
    'SNP_belongTo_Gene',
    'TF_regulates',
    'TranseQTL_belongTo_Gene',
    'TranseQTL_to_gene',
    'ciseQTL_belongTo_Gene',
    'ciseQTL_influence_Gene',
    'environmenteqtl_id_on',
    'gene_to_TFfamily',
    'subaloaction',
    'Gene_Phenotypes_affected_by_Gene_from_twas_araPhenotype',
    'PPI',
    'TF_regulates'
]
WITH gds.graph.project(
  'graphdealj',
  source,
  target,
  {
    sourceNodeLabels: labels(source),
    targetNodeLabels: labels(target),
    relationshipType: type(r)
  }
) AS g
RETURN g.graphName AS graph, g.nodeCount AS nodes, g.relationshipCount AS rels
```

But I get this error:

```
Unknown function 'gds.graph.project' (line 47, column 6 (offset: 1700))
"    'TF_regulates'"
                   ^
```

I am absolutely certain that I have installed GDS, as I'm able to successfully execute other methods of projection and various algorithms. Also, the part of the query before the final GDS section executes without any issues:

[image]

I tried adding a `call` after `with`, but it didn't work, but I can guarantee that the code is executed normally before the last `with`. You can see that the picture has output

Comment: Does the following query return anything? `SHOW FUNCTIONS YIELD name WHERE name = 'gds.graph.project' RETURN name`

Comment: it return "no change,no records"

Comment: That means the GDS plugin is not installed or configured correctly.

Comment: my gds.version() is 2.2.6

Comment: So, `RETURN gds.version()` returns "2.2.6"? If so, that should mean the GDS plugin is installed. Try re-installing GDS (ideally, to the latest version compatible with your neo4j version).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the installed GDS version? (RETURN gds.version())
The current docs point to 2.4 but I suspect you have an older version installed.

Comment: gds.version()
"2.2.6"， yes my gds version is 2.2.6

Comment: So then best you update GDS or look at https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/2.2/introduction/